# Unable to change virtual machine power state: This host supports AMD-V, but AMD-V is disabled

Tags: virtualization, vmware, amd-processor

When I try to run VMware, I'm getting

> Unable to change virtual machine power state: This host supports AMD-V, but AMD-V is disabled.
>   AMD-V might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: that is for virtual box. But I am on ubuntu distro and will try to see if there is an option to enable/disable virtualizaion in the bios

Comment: Have you tried changing settings in BIOS?

Comment: let me try to find how to change the settings in bios in my machine

Comment: thanks just needed to enable SVM/virtualization now its booting up and setting up windows on a vm

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

On MSI Motherboard enter BIOS mode and turn:

```
SVM: enable
```